# Combining data to generate routes in a graph. Where to start?

Tags: mysql, algorithm, graph, routes, neo4j

I'm not even really sure the title of this question best reflect what I really want to do and the actual question content is also quite confusing as I'm not sure what I really need, but I'm counting on you guys to help me out.

I'm trying to find out the best way to generate, based on simple direct routes, more complex and multi-path routes on a flight search app.

Let's say I have two flight routes in my Routes table:

```
Origin              Destination
MIA (Miama)         ATL (Atlanta) and
ATL (Atlanta)       LAX (Los Angeles)
```

By having these two routes and issuing a simple query such as:

```
SELECT ... FROM  Routes WHERE origin = 'MIA' AND destination = 'LAX'
```

I get no results, but if I'm able to combine all data I have, then I will be able to offer such route going through ATL (Atlanta): MIA -> ATL -> LAX.

I'm looking into Neo4J to hold my data and perform my searches using the shortest path, but I'm not sure I need such a big gun. As of now I'm using MySql and If I structure my data correctly I think I should be able to do it.

I've looked into the shortest path algorithm with Neo4J (http://blog.neo4j.org/2013/08/finding-shortest-path-through-park.html) but there are some other questions I have regarding as how to approach this since I'm pretty new to this kind of problems.

So my questions are:

1. Should I use my base direct routes to pre-compute complex routes such as MIA -> LAX or should I use a tool/algorithm to generate this on the fly based on the data I have?
2. If I pre-compute the complex routes, where do I start? Any algorithms hints? This is where most of my difficult lies.
3. Do I need a graphing database for this or is MySql fine? I have about 35k different base routes and no more than 10 requests per second on this.
4. I also would like to limit my results to routes no more than 3 or 4 legs away since routes bigger than this might connect the whole world in a very weird and long flight

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think you should let algorithm calculate your routes on the fly as it would be more flexible design wise and when you update with more data(routes in this case) , you wont have to compute and store complex routes additionally
2. refer 1
3. Yes with graph database your queries will be faster. For comparison check here: [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/mysql-vs-neo4j-large-scale).There are many such comparisons and benchmarks tested and uploaded , you can google it.
4. you can easily do that by limiting the number of hops in your cypher query (query language for neo4j)

So in your case the graph will be kind of

```
(MIA)-[:CONNECTS]->(ATL)-[:CONNECTS]->(LAX)
```

So you would just need to query

```
MATCH p=(f:LOCATION)-[:CONNECTS*1..3]->(g:LOCATION) where f.name = "MIA" and g.name="LAX" return nodes(p) as ConnectingAirports
```

So if you index the `LOCATION` nodes on the `name` attribute, it will make your query even faster. Also the above query will not only give you the `ATL` but also all other route locations interconnected by `CONNECTS` relation and which are 1,2 or 3 hops away from `MIA` location.